# How to delete only few elements in Node List?

Tags: javascript

I have a function `clearBoth` where I grab all elements with class 'clear' and remove them. However I 
  would like to keep 2 of them. Right now I get rid of all elements with a class 'clear' and then create 
  again 2 which I assume is not a very good solution.

```
function clearBoth(postContent) {
  var clearElem = document.querySelector('.clear');
  if(typeof(clearElem) !== "undefined" && clearElem !==null) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.clear').forEach(function(a) {
      a.remove()
   })
  var clearBoth1 = document.createElement('br');
     clearBoth1.className = 'clear';
     postContent.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", clearBoth1 );

  var clearBoth2 = document.createElement('br')
     clearBoth2.className = 'clear';
     postContent.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", clearBoth2);
 } else {
  var clearBoth3 = document.createElement('br')
     clearBoth3.className = 'clear';
     postContent.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", clearBoth3);

  var clearBoth4 = 
     document.createElement('br')
     clearBoth4.className = 'clear';
  postContent.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", clearBoth4 );
  }
}
```

Comment: `typeof(clearElem) !== "undefined"` will always be `true` because `.querySelector()` either returns `null` or an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try using a combination of `:not` and an `nth-range`? This will select every element with the exception of the last two:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.clear:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2)');
```

<s>Additionally, your forEach will not work. Reason being, you're trying to invoke an array based method when in reality you have an `HTMLCollection`. You'll have to convert the collection using a bevy of options: [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):</s>

NodeLists do in fact have their own [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) but by user request I left this solution here in the event an HTMLCollection needs to access methods from the `Array.prototype`:

**Array.from()**

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.clear:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))')).forEach(...);
```

---

**call**

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.clear:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))')).forEach(...);
```

---

**Spread Syntax**

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.clear:not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))')].forEach(...);
```

Comment: Or `[...document.querySelectorAll('.clear')].slice(0, -2).forEach(x => x.remove())`

Comment: I was thinking of incorporating slice but is it not more performant and terse just to write out the exclusion in your selector?

Comment: @CarlEdwards NodeList has `forEach` method

Comment: I always mess up those "complex" selectors hence I would use the "easy" one^^

Comment: @Andreas I don't think there is a grantee that the OP just want to save last two elements of his selection.

Comment: @Charlie You're absolutely right. I'll redact that last part. I'm so used to trying to map collections and converting them that this one went right over my head. Thanks.

Comment: @Carl Edwards You could have keeped paragraphs about spread operator and Array.from method. It was good. Thank you!

Comment: @brad_fresh Np. Put it back up.